# On which algorithm for boosting is the method xgbLinear of the xgboost/caret- package based on?

Tags: machine-learning, r, xgboost

In caret package of R, there is a method 'xgblinear'. What is the working algorithm behind this method.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is helpful or not but here is a link to an academic paper detailing both the algorithm behind XGBoost and some use cases.

http://dmlc.cs.washington.edu/data/pdf/XGBoostArxiv.pdf

Answer (score 0):

It's the usual XGBoost boosting, but with linear models instead of decision trees as the base learner.

There are several questions about this over at stats.SE; here's a quick sampling:
[What exactly is the gblinear booster in XGBoost?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/521549/232706)
[How does linear base learner works in boosting? And how does it works in the xgboost library?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/230388/232706)
[Difference in regression coefficients of sklearn's LinearRegression and XGBRegressor](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/448879/232706)